# Why Fiddler introduce delay when we set Expect header with 100-continue?

Tags: libcurl, fiddler

When the client set Expect header with 100-continue, Fiddler add around 1 sec latency to the request.

And it can be fixed by following this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/modify-traffic/tasks/continuerequestheaders).
Next question is, why Fiddler has this overhead?

Answer (score 1):

More info:
So the client is LibCurl.
And apparently when Expect header is present with value of `100-continue`, LibCurl will wait up to 1 sec before sending the remaining body.

This is as per [spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3). This blog post ([About the HTTP Expect: 100-continue header](https://www.bram.us/2020/04/14/about-the-http-expect-100-continue-header/)) explains this behavior well.